# this keyword in java

Tags: java, this, keyword

I am current reading a java tutorial from Oracle in the inner class section.

Please refer to [**this link**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html)

There is some code that I do not understand in the tutorial.

Can somebody please explain to me how this code below in the `DataStructure` class works?

```
DataStructureIterator iterator = this.new EvenIterator();
```

Should the outer class not be before `DataStructureIterator iterator` and `this.new EvenIterator()` like below:

```
DataStructure.DataStructureIterator iterator = DataStructure.this.new EvenIterator();
```

I have searched around for a while but I have not found any answer.

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ:  I'm not sure I buy that yet...yes, it's using `this`, but it's using it in an unconventional way.  I didn't even realize you could *do* that with `this`.

Comment: Where is the code that executes that line? `this` is the enclosing instance needed for an inner class instance creation.

Comment: Wow, how long did it take you to search the entire Internet?  Did you have to download it to a floppy first?

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ - No way is this a duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

The declaration `DataStructure.DataStructureIterator iterator = DataStructure.this.new EvenIterator();` is valid, but redundant in that method's context.

Consider this scenario, where there are conflicting inner classes

```
public void printEven() {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Makes EvenIterator point to DataStructure's implementation
            DataStructureIterator itr = DataStructure.this.new EvenIterator();
        }

        class EvenIterator implements DataStructureIterator {

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public Integer next() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void remove() {
            }

        }
    });
}
```

As you can see the anonymous class `Runnable` has inner class named `EvenIterator` (which has same name as Outer class's inner class). So writing just

```
DataStructureIterator itr = this.new EvenIterator(); //OR DataStructureIterator itr = new EvenIterator();
```

will refer to `Runnable`'s `EvenIterator`. To point to `DataStructure`'s `EvenIterator`, you might want to write

```
DataStructureIterator itr = DataStructure.this.new EvenIterator();
```

Which says, I want `EvenIterator` to be created on ***current instance*** of `DataStructure`, not current instance of `Runnable`

Answer (score 2):

"this keyword" refer to the scope of an object class so :

```
public class Test {
     public void method1(){
         this. //this in here refer to "Test" class
     }

     public class InnerTest {
        public void method2(){
           this. //this in here refer to "InnerTest" class
        }
     }
}
```

now take a look at "this keyword" in this example :

```
public class Test {
     public void method1(){

         InnerTest innerTest = this.new InnerTest(); //within the scope of Test class, there's a inner class call InnerTest. create an instance of it !
         //OR
         TestInterface innerTest2 = this.new InnerTest(); //within the scope of Test class, there's a inner class call InnerTest. create an instance of it !
     }

     public class InnerTest implements TestInterface{
        public void method2(){
           Test.this.method1(); //within the scope of "Test" class call the method method1
        }
     }
}
```

take note that you can use this keyword to chain the constructor of a class as well. take a look at this example:

```
public class Test {

    public Test() {
        this(0);
    }

    public Test(int r) {
        // Do Something Here
    }
}
```

**Conclusion:**

"this" keyword acts like a **pointer to the scope of a class** and using "this" you can point to a specific class and do whatever you want.

You can also use "this" keyword to **chain class constructors** as well !

Answer (score 1):

```
public class DataStructure {
    /** omitted */

    public void printEven() {
       //#1
       DataStructureIterator iterator = this.new EvenIterator();
       /** Omitted */
    }

    //#2
    private class EvenIterator implements DataStructureIterator {
      /** Omitted */
    }
}
```

So this is the bare-bone problem.

Lets see what we have:

1. A class `DataStructure` that has a non-static method `printEven`. the `this` keyword in this class will *always* represent the current instance/object of this class: `DataStructure`.
2. An inner class, that is private. This means this class is not visible outside. It is not static that means you need an instance of outer-class to be able to instanciate this class-member (aka inner class).

So, we want to create an instance of `EvenIterator`, we will need a. an instance of outer class, b. call a constructor of inner class.

```
  DataStructureIterator iterator = this.new EvenIterator();
                                     |        `---- Call to constructor
                                     `-------------- instance of outer class
```

Doing `DataStructure.this` in `DataStructure` is redundant. Because we know that we are in the scope of `DataStructure` so just `this` will do. **However, if you are in inner class `EvenIterator`, and you want to explicitely access outer class's instance you will have to to do `DataStructure.this`, because in inner class `this` will mean the instance of `EvenIterator`.**

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `this` is actually written in the outer class, not the inner class, in your specific example.  Therefore, it's not ambiguous in any way - it can only refer to the `DataStructure` instance.  It's therefore unnecessary (but legal) to qualify it as `DataStructure.this` in this case.  If you used `this` within the inner class, and you intended it to refer to the `DataStructure` instance, you would have to write `DataStructure.this`.

According to the [Java Language Specification 15.8.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3) -

> The type of this is the class C within which the keyword this occurs.